# Postgresql: inner join on 3 tables if data in 2. table is of no interest

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Assuming I have the following three tables:

```
a
------
id
p1
b_id

b
------
id
c_id
other_value

c
------
id
p2
```

To get all the p1 and p2 values, I would write the following query:

```
SELECT 
    a.p1, c.p2
FROM
    a
INNER JOIN
    b ON (a.b_id = b.id)
INNER JOIN
    c ON (b.c_id = c.id)
```

Now, since I'm not really interested in the `other_value` inside of `b`, I wondered if there is a simpler way to find the corresponding p2 value for each `a` entry.

(The reason for this question is that I'm running into performance problems on a database with a similar, but more complex, structure)

Comment: The b_id and c_id are foreign keys (into the b and c table, obviously) It helps to add indexes for them (and run vacuum analyze)  BTW: show us your query plan, et cetera.

Comment: BTW: of course you need the b-table: it is the only link between a and c.

Comment: @joop thanks for your remarks. I kind of start thinking that I'm on the wrong track. My main goal is to increase performance and I thought performing a join on two tables and then never use the values is probably not the most efficient solution. The ids are already indexed by the way.

Comment: The IDs (PKs) are supposed to be indexed. indexing the FKs (a.b_id and b.c_id) is an explicit manual task.

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on avoiding the `b` table in the outer scope, here is a nice *ugly* solution:

```
SELECT *
    -- a.p1, c.p2
FROM a,c
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 42
   FROM b 
   WHERE b.id = a.b_id
   AND b.c_id = c.id
   );
```

---

The same, using `JOIN` syntax (yields exactly the same query plan)

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN c ON EXISTS (
   SELECT 42
   FROM b
   WHERE b.id = a.b_id
   AND b.c_id = c.id
   );
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to answer the actual question, although i guess it will perform worse? I will test it....

Comment: It will perform exactly the same, unless your `b` table is a N:M junction table. (I presume it is a 1:n junction table)